# Class A contains a list of Class B and two lists of Class C. Class B also has two lists of Class C. How to map? Find by ID breaks

Tags: java, spring, orm, h2

I'm developing a tabletop game using Spring + H2 database. Currently, I'm facing an ORM issue. I have three classes: `cards`, `players`, and `tabletop`.

The `tabletop` class has two lists of `cards` and a list of `players`. Players, in turn, have two lists of `cards`. How should I handle the mapping?

I can successfully save data to the database, but when I attempt to findById for the `tabletop`, the associated objects become `null`.

I tried to map using :

```java
  @Entity
  public class Tabletop{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "tabletop")
    private BaseCards baseCards;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "tabletop")
    private FieldCards fieldCards;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tabletop_id")
    private List<Player> players;
  }
  @Entity
  public class Player {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "player")
    private PlayerHandCards handCards;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "player")
    private PlayerBinCards binCards;

  }
  @Entity
  public class PlayerHandCards {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="player_hand_id")
    List<Cards> Cards;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "player_id")
    private Player player;

  }
  @Entity
  public class PlayerBinCards {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="player_bin_id")
    List<Cards> cards;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "player_id")
    private Player player;

  }
  @Entity
  public class BaseCards {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="base_cards_id")
    List<Cards> cards;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Tabletop_id")
    private Tabletop tabletop;

  }

  @Entity
  public class FieldCards {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="field_cards_id")
    List<Cards> cards;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Tabletop_id")
    private Tabletop tabletop;

  }
  @Entity
  public class Cards{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String color;

    private Integer value;

  }
```

Comment: Please add the class `FieldCards`.

Comment: it is the same as BaseCards but I did anyway

Comment: Having a relation between two entities (1-1, 1-n, n-m) we have a owning-side and a non-owning side. Make sure you connect and save them using the owning-side and not the non-owning side only. No, you know what? Bind them vice-versa and you are good to go.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean but I just create BaseCards and PlayerBinCards because 
@JoinColumn(name = "tabletop_id")
    private List<Cards> baseCards/playerBinCards ;
is creating in Cards's table the same id to all cards of a field, the same goes with players. I tried to retrieve these data and it is a mess

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found out the solution and my mistakes.
I created 2 `@OneToOne` relationships with the same id and what I should have done was

```java
@OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "player_hand_cards",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "player _id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "card_id")
    )
    private List<Cards> playerHandCards = new ArrayList<>();
```